# Android Studio - Cannot reload AVD list (d:skin)

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I'm trying to get google maps on an application on my android device. I was testing how it works so i started with adding a simple map. However when i try to run it it gives me this error.

**Cannot reload AVD list: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error parsing /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/system-images/android-22/android-wear/armeabi-v7a/devices.xml
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'd:skin'. No child element is expected at this point.
Error parsing /Applications/Android Studio.app/sdk/system-images/android-22/android-wear/x86/devices.xm**

My code is very simple, i created a prefab google maps activity and just filled in my Android API key like they said in the guide.

Does anyone knows how to fix this?

Comment: Hey people for who might have the same problem. I still got the error but i quickly clicked OK and then i pressed "use same device for the future" and ran the app on my device. Now he doesn't display the error anymore however its still there.

Comment: Do you get this error for just load the map or others android app also cause the problem?

Comment: @bjiang Also on other apps

Comment: You can try to use `genymotion` which is better emulator of android.

Comment: did you find a fix? I'm using genymotions though I still have the issue

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The solution is to delete Android Wear ARM & Intel images:

[image]

Comment: what if I need the android wear image as well?